# How can I manage changes in desired capacity due to scaling policies in AutoScaling Group state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling, capacity-planning

How can I manage changes in desired capacity due to scaling policies in AutoScaling Group state in terraform?

Specifically, suppose I provision an [aws_autoscaling_group resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html) with terraform with a [desired_capacity](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#desired_capacity) of 4 and a scaleup policy on high CPU utilization. Later, the autoscaling group has updated via scaling policies to a desired capacity of 6 but this state isn't captured in my terraform .tfstate.

If I want to make a subsequent change to my autoscaling group state via terraform, how can I make the change without resetting the desired_capacity (since it has not changed in the .tf)? Can I automate updating the desired_capacity to match current group size somehow, or should I just not set desired_capacity at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `desired_capacity` in Terraform is marked [in the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#desired_capacity) as optional. So with a proper `min_size` value, Terraform [can wait](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#waiting-for-capacity) until the minimum capacity is reached before continuing.

The above, with the addition of scale policy can effectively manage capacity without being specific about `desired_capacity` in your Terraform code. This will prevent you from having Terraform override the capacity in place at the moment of execution.